# Bootstrap, webfont on windows -> euro accent are bolder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, diacritics, euro

I've got a problem with euro accents on windows (on linux everything is ok). Just lets see the screenshot

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ziysatyhjwstlsc/01.jpg

How can I fix it?

**edit:**
in code i've got:

```
font-family: Ubuntu, Tahoma;
```

and whole page is using Ubuntu but euro accents are in Tahoma - but only on windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try adding

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

in the head of your page